# My toString method using a loop shows an output with a missing element, how do I fix it?

Tags: java, loops, tostring

I'm using BlueJ to do this and I am having an issue with the toString bit. I have only just started programming so excuse me if I'm not aware of all the technical aspects.
This is my code:

```
public String toString()
{
    String s = "{" + list[0]; 

    for ( int i = 0 ; i < list.length-1 ; i++ ) 
    {
        i = i+1;
        s = s + ", " + list[i];
        i = i+1;
        s = s + ", " + list[i];
        i = i+1;
        s = s + ", " + list[i];
    }

    s = s + "}";
    return s;

} // method toString
```

I am using a loop because my array is declared as:

```
public ListOfNVersion01PartB(int [] element)
{
    list = new int[element.length]; 
    for (int i=0 ; i<element.length ; ++i )
         list[i] = element[i];

} // constructor ListOfNVersion01Skeleton(int [] element)
```

The output of this is:

({2,4,7,3}) <-- this is one array

.toString() -> "{2, 4, 7, 3}" <--this output is correct

({1,2,3,4,9,8,7,6 <-- this is another

.toString() -> "{1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 7, 6} <-- this output is missing the 9

How do I fix this?
Keep in mind that I can't add any classes because it needs to have the same structure as the benchmark output. 
Please help.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `i`, the loop index, **within** the for loop? That is a very dangerous thing to do. You will want to read a tutorial on how for loops work, because many of the lines of code within the loop and the incrementing of the index shouldn't be done.

Comment: Hint: This will only work properly when the length of the array is 1 more than a multiple of 3.

Comment: Just do `s += list[i]`

Answer (score 1):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("{");
for(String element: list){
    sb.append(element);
    sb.append(",");
}
return sb.subSequence(0, sb.length()-1) + "}";
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you don't have enough control on your i variable. Another thing is that it's always a good practice to check your input first. I think following code can help you.

```
public String toString(){
    if(list == null || list.length==0)return "{}";
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("{"+list[0]);
    for(int i=0;i<list.length-1;i++){
        sb.append(","+list[i]);
    }
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple string is easy enough to work with.

Try this.

```
 public String toString()
    {
        String s="{"+list[0];

        for(int i=1; i<list.length;i++) //starting at second element since first was placed in string
        {
            s+=", "+list[i];                
        }

        s+="}";

        return s;
    }
```

Let the loop iterate through the array.